# How to know if the element is on the screen?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a horizontal ListBox with Images, which are pretty big and take 80% of the screen. User scrolls through this ListBox and images change quickly, and I'd like to highlight the image which is actually on the screen. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Not that I'm trying to be a smart a.. but if the image already covers 80% of the screen, why do you need to highlight it? Isn't it already obvious?

Comment: the case is that there are images which are not as big, so user can see neighbour images as well, and the idea was to draw a border around the center image

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use the class proposed by AnthonyWJones in this topic:
[Restoring exact scroll position of a listbox in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475537/restoring-exact-scroll-position-of-a-listbox-in-windows-phone-7)

The idea remains the same. You'll just change the vertical listbox to horizontal listbox.
Thus, you can recover the exact position of your listbox.